# jquery :not selector question (combine Descendant Selector with :not)

Tags: jquery

I try to combine the Descendant Selector `(.a .b)` (only select items with class .b if they are an indirect child of .a). With the `:not(.a)` (only select if it's not class .a)  selector.

I setup a simple example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eqj1p3gf/1/

I want to select all elements with the class .wanted, but only if they are not an indirect child of an element with the class .aaa.:

```
<div class="aaa">
  <div class="something">
    <div class="wanted">
      I don't want this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bbb">
  <div class="somethingelse">
    <div class="wanted">
      I only want this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For that I try to use this selector: `$(":not(.aaa)  .wanted")`, but it selects both .wanted elements because both elements have a parent that is not `.aaa`.

How could I create such a selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make such a selection you first want to select all `.wanted` elements and then use `:not` to deselect all `.wanted` elements with a parent `.aaa`:

```
$(".wanted:not(.aaa .wanted)").css("text-transform", "uppercase");
```